# In differential equation, why do we have a different interval for an integral?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I found in a physics book that if we have a differential equation of the form $\frac{dN}{N}=-\lambda dt$ then we can integrate both sides to get $\int_{N_0}^N\frac{dN}{N}=-\lambda\int_0^t dt$. Is there a book or lecture notes that explains what happens here? Why do we integrate left hand side from $N_0$ to $N$ and the right hand side from $0$ to $t$? Is it just a sloppy notation for initial value problem?

Comment: It guarantees that when $t=0$, $N=N_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go over the formula that uses the two differentials $dt, dN$ as separate algebraic entities (and not as closing symbols to the opening integral sign), then the following integration is not over a time interval $I=[t_0,t_1]$, but over a line segment $S=[(t_0,N_0),(t_1,N_1)]$ in the $t$-$N$-plane. These curve integrals then reduce to the scalar integrals as the particular integrals used are strictly in one coordinate.

If that is too advanced, just avoid differential forms and work with the substitution rule that is the basis for this "trick", the separation method,
$$
−λ\int_{t_0}^{t_1}dt=\int_{t_0}^{t_1}\frac{N'(t)}{N(t)}dt=\int_{N(t_0)}^{N(t_1)}\frac{dN}{N}.
$$

Comment: Definitely the best answer, and the only accurate one. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Differential equation for a decay model:

$${dN \over dt} = - \lambda N(t) $$

Initial Condition: $N(0) = N_0$ (initial population)

Here, $\lambda > 0$ is the *decay* constant.

Separating the variables, we get

$$ {dN(t) \over N(t)} = - \lambda dt $$

Integrating both sides, we get
$$
\ln| N(t)| = - \lambda t + k,
$$
where $k$ is an integration constant.

(No need to put limits for the integrals.)

Now, we apply the initial condition to determine $k$ :

$$ N(0) = N_0.$$

Thus,
$$
\ln | N_0 | = k
$$

Hence,
$$
\ln | N(t) | - \ln | N_0 | = - \lambda t
$$
or
$$
\ln\left| {N(t) \over N_0} \right| = - \lambda t
$$

i.e.
$$
N(t) = N_0 e^{-\lambda t}
$$

This is why the decay model is also called an exponential model...

To elaborate my answer to the query regarding the limits of integration (why some books are showing different limits for integration), let us revisit the step where the variables are separated and ready for integration.. (I showed this in my calculation as well)

$$
{dN(t) \over N(t)} = - \lambda dt
$$

Taking limits on both sides from $0$ (initial time) to $t$, we get

$$
\int\limits_{\tau = 0}^t  \ {dN(\tau) \over N(\tau)} \ d\tau =
- \lambda \int\limits_{\tau = 0}^t \ d\tau
$$

After integration, we get
$$
\left[ \ln(N(\tau)) \right]_{\tau = 0}^t =
- \lambda [\tau]_{\tau = 0}^t
$$

Substituting for the limits and simplifying (noting that $N(0) = N_0$ is the initial population), we get

$$
\left[ \ln|N(t)| - \ln|N_0| \right] = - \lambda t
$$
or
$$
 \ln\left|{N(t)  \over N_0} \right|   = -\lambda t
$$

which can be rearranged as
$$
N(t) = N_0 e^{-\lambda t}
$$

I explained the interval query implicitly in my first answer, but I elaborated it as it was not clear to some readers. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which was about the limits of integration.

Comment: I will elaborate my answer..

Answer (score 0):

The book is merely abusing notation; what it shows is equivalent to indefinitely integrating $\frac1N \frac{dN}{dt}=-\lambda$ with respect to $t,$ then plugging $(0,N_0)$ into $(t,N)$ to obtain a particular solution.